# Displaying Facebook Comments From FB Comment Box on a Website on Facebook Business Page Timeline

Tags: facebook, api

I have a client who wants their websites Facebook comments (from comment box) to be displayed on their Facebook Business Page.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I've got iframe installed on a tab on the business homepage now. Inside the iframe I have this code:
<div style="margin-top: 10px;"> 
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="fb-comments"  data-href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" data-num-posts="20" data-width="660" data-colorscheme="dark" style="padding-left:10px;"></div>

Comment: I need to use "<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" becuase the comment box is loaded on a php page which has different urls

With code above in iframe I see the comment box but getting the error "Warning: http://invalid.invalid/?php%20echo%20HTTP_SERVER%20.%20$_SERVER%5B'REQUEST_URI'%5D;%20?> is unreachable."

Comment: Strangly if I add this code to the ifram instead, it pulls up hundereds of comments from another chat presumably taking place on facebook somewhere:


<div style="margin-top: 10px;"> 
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="fb-comments"  data-href="<base href="<?php echo (($request_type == 'SSL') ? HTTPS_SERVER : HTTP_SERVER) . DIR_WS_CATALOG; ?></div></td>

So I think its possible, but not adding the right url to the ifram seems to be the problem now.

Comment: if i use url data-href="connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=myappid" the comment box is shown in the iframe but none of the comments are there

Answer (score 0):

Create a iframe application, put the comments plugin there and specified the data-href/href (html5/xfbml) to be exactly the same as the one on their page ...

Comment: Hello, I have created iframe application, added a page tab to the facebook business page, but im still not sure which url or how to put the comment plug in there? It is asking for Page Tab URL:? If I put the main website url in, it will show the entire page, but I only want to show the comments?